# Use of a 2D HashMap

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I have a text file as input and I am trying to find the number of times every word of the file appears as well as how many times it appears on each line. So for the word "banana" I would like an output like: {banana: 5,0,0,1,1,1} meaning that "banana" appears 5 times in the text, 2 times in the first line (0) and 3 times in the second line.

I am thinking of using a 2D HashMap for that so that:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>
```

where String is the word, the first Integer is the line the word appears at, and the second Integer the number of occurrences in the line. The problem is that I cannot implement my idea in code as I get many errors:

```
Map<Map<Integer,Integer>, String > hashOfHash = new HashMap<Map<Integer, Integer>, String>();


    while (line!=null){
        Map<Integer, Integer> hash = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        String[] words = line.split(" ");

        for (String z:words){
                if (hashOfHash.containsKey(z)) {
                    Integer r = hashOfHash.get(z);
                    r = r + 1;
                } else {
                    hash.put(z, new Integer(1));
                }           
        }

    }
```

Could anyone please assist me with the problem?

Comment: What are your "many errors"?  Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Start with the first error reported.  Fix that, then see what errors remain.  Chances are that you'll not need to fix nearly as many bugs is you get errors, as often one bug triggers many different errors.

Comment: You've stated that you're thinking of `Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>`, but then, right away, you're providing code with `Map<Map<Integer,Integer>, String>`...

Comment: Yes Alex, this is what I was thinking. Using one hashmap to store the other hashmap inside it as well. The first would contain the words as keys and those keys would correspond to the two Integers of the maps, one for the line and one for the occurrences. Think it could work?

Answer (score 2):

I would make a class that wraps your functionality for you:

```
public class WordInfo {

    private int occurrences = 0; //Store total occurances
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> lines = new TreeMap<>(); //Map line numbers to occurance counts

    public void markLine(int line) {
        Integer curr = this.lines.get(line);
        if (curr == null) {
            curr = 0;
        }
        this.lines.put(line, ++curr);
    }

    public int getOccurrences() {
        return this.occurrences;
    }

    public int getOccurrencesAtLine(int line) {
        return this.lines.containsKey(line) ? this.lines.get(line) : 0;
    }

    public Map<Integer, Integer> getOccurrenceLocations() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.lines);
    }

}
```

Then it simply becomes a matter of managing your own mapping to this class appropriately (some example methods):

```
private final Map<String, WordInfo> wordInfo = new HashMap<>(); //Use to retrieve info about words

private WordInfo getInfo(String word) {
    WordInfo back = this.wordInfo.get(word);
    if (back == null) {
        back = new WordInfo();
        this.wordInfo.put(word, back);
    }
    return back;
}

public void markWord(String word, int line) { //Call upon occurance of a word
    this.getInfo(word).markLine(line);
}
```

You're working in a language which is essentially all object-orientated, it helps to make objects which represent your information rather than combining confusing amounts of Collections and Maps.

As for your specific example, you could easily convert to a string like so:

```
public String wordInfo(String word) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
    WordInfo info = this.getInfo(word);
    sb.append(word).append(": ").append(info.getOccurrences());
    info.getOccurrenceLocations().entrySet().forEach(ent -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < ent.getValue(); i++) { //#getValue() -> occcurences at a line
            sb.append(",").append(ent.getKey()); //#getKey() -> line number
        }
    });
    return sb.append("}").toString();
}
```

Would output like

```
{banana: 0} //no occurrences
{banana: 1,1} //one occurrence on line 1
{banana: 5,0,0,1,1,1} //5 occurrences, 2 on line "0", 3 on line "1"
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help. A question, why use a TreeMap for the lines instead of HashMap? What are the benefits of doing that?

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand where I am supposed to input the text here to test the code

Comment: I used a TreeMap instead of a HashMap so that the keys would be sorted in natural-order (it would list the lines in proper order that way). As for utilizing this, you would have the "WordInfo" class as a new class, and then utilize it as a map value however you wish (as I provided examples of its usage).